# Using XPATH in xslt:value-of select to populate attritube

Tags: xslt, xpath, attributes, value-of

XML Data:

```
<ProcessData>
    <OUTPUT>
        <SourceAgent>Agent1</SourceAgent>
        <DestinationAgent>Agent2</DestinationAgent>
    </OUTPUT>
</ProcessData>
```

XSLT:

```
<sourceAgent QMgr="BSCMFT01" agent="'<xsl:value-of select="/ProcessData/OUTPUT/SourceAgent/text()"/>'"/>
<destinationAgent QMgr="BSCMFT01" agent="'<xsl:value-of select="/ProcessData/OUTPUT/DestinationAgent/text()"/>'"/>
```

Desired Output:

```
<sourceAgent QMgr="BSCMFT01" agent="Agent1"/>
<destinationAgent QMgr="BSCMFT01" agent="Agent2"/>
```

Error:
The value of attribute "agent" associated with an element type "sourceAgent" must not contain the '<' character.

Summary:

- Using XSLT 1.0
- I've tried escaping the ">" and "<" using "&lt ;" and "&gt ;"

Answer (score 1):

Use either the [`xsl:attribute`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#creating-attributes) instruction:

```
<sourceAgent QMgr="BSCMFT01">
    <xsl:attribute name="agent">
        <xsl:value-of select="/ProcessData/OUTPUT/SourceAgent"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</sourceAgent>
```

or [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates):

```
<sourceAgent QMgr="BSCMFT01" agent="{/ProcessData/OUTPUT/SourceAgent}"/>
```